# Feathersjs get data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nodemailer, feathersjs

Would like to get email and password from mongodb. Data will be used to fill the mailer smtpTransport method

```
app.use('/mailer', Mailer`(smtpTransport({
   service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
       user: email,
       pass: password
}
```

Is it possible to use a hook to pass the data to Mailer service. If so how.

Comment: Feathers uses express, a service is a middleware, and a hooks can be attached to a service. So it depends where did you add your service to that `app.use()` will it be before or after that mailer.

But my advice to you is that do your mailer inside the `service hook`, in this case, a mailer service?

Comment: I have mailer as a custom service. I would like to set var email and password prior to calling app.use. But how would I do that.

Comment: Would it be better to create a mongoose service. The request the email and password for gmail user in a before method?

Comment: Yeah, that one will work too. But if you can do that, why not get those data before even calling the email service?

Comment: How would I do this before calling the service?